# Can I implement text or link sharing from my app to StockTwits in iOS

Tags: ios, stocktwits

I try add StockTwits to UIActivity in my app, can I do it without registering my app on stocktwits.com/developers? I don't want obtain user info or something else, only share an url (of course if StockTwits app exist on user device).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to register your app on the StockTwits developer portal for any interaction with read/write activity with StockTwits. You can do so here: http://stocktwits.com/developers